# Getting syntax error while trying to download the file using Python

Tags: python

I need to read/download the file provided by user using Python but it's giving me syntax error.

Error:

> File "path1.py", line 6
>           return HttpResponse(content=test_file, content_type="text/plain")
>       SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

My code is below:

```
import os
from django.http import HttpResponse
#image_name = request.GET.get('param')
image_name = "63b6ac1bc61642f39c697585810aed17.txt"
test_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_name)
return HttpResponse(content=test_file, content_type="text/plain")
```

Actually here my requirement is if I am providing the filename and need to read/download this file using Python.

Comment: remove the return statement. You can only return when inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

The code says exactly what is the problem. You use `return` statemmnt outside function. You need to define one to be able to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

The error told you all you want. You are not using a function, but you are returning something. How can you return something if you don't call it?

Try this:

```
import os
from django.http import HttpResponse
def downloadFile():
   #image_name = request.GET.get('param')
   image_name = "63b6ac1bc61642f39c697585810aed17.txt"
   test_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_name)
   return HttpResponse(content=test_file, content_type="text/plain")

downloadFile()
```

Comment: Be quick or be dead :D

Comment: @VíctorLópez : Error gone but its neither read nor download the file.